# Forbidden transitions from triplet to singlet states in the deuteron?

Tags: nuclear-physics, quantum-spin, dipole-moment

The dipolar moment for the deuteron is
$$\vec{\mu}_{d}=\frac{\mu_{N}}{2 h}\left\{\left(g_{s}^{(p)}+g_{s}^{(n)}\right) \vec{S}+\left(g_{s}^{(p)}-g_{s}^{(n)}\right)\left(\vec{s}_{p}-\vec{s}_{n}\right)+\vec{L}\right\}$$
we know could understad that
$$\left(\vec{s}_{p}-\vec{s}_{n}\right)=0$$
in the deuteron if we suppose that proton and neutron are too similar. But I find that people use to interpret that as forbbiden transition from triplet to singlet. Why transitions from triplet to singlet would be allowed if $\left(\vec{s}_{p}-\vec{s}_{n}\right)\neq 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tensor part of the nuclear force contains a term $-(\vec{s_1}\cdot\vec{s_2})$. This means that the spin triplet state is at a **lower** energy than the spin singlet state; in fact, due to the deuteron's miniscule binding energy, the spin singlet state is unbound, making the spin triplet the only bound state.

Comment: The fact that the miniscule binding energy in the deuteron could be predicted using only theory or is an experimental fact?

Comment: @Elpis Depends on what you mean by "using only theory". It can be calculated using a phenomenological nucleon-nucleon potential, but the relevant features of this model are informed by experimental measurements, rather than first principles.